# Is there a Waze-like app to keep track of each other among travel companions?

Tags: cellphones, gear, gps-navigation

I am an avid user of [Waze](https://www.waze.com). One of its feature is the ability to share your location with followers or through text messaging. This is quite handy when you are on route to appointment while being stuck in traffic. You simply sent a message and the recipient can follow where you are and when you'll arrive.

Unfortunately, only works when driving. It does not cater walking, cycling or public transportation. Does an equivalent of waze exists, which would allow you to share where you are. I would very much like to use this while traveling with a group.

A google search on the matter reveals some apps, but these are mainly aimed at couples who don't trust each other, where you would need to be sneaky when installing the app the phone of the person you would like to follow.

I would like to be able to simple send a text message to have someone be able to follow me, similar like the approach waze is taking. 
Does such an app exist?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, there's an app *exactly* for what you're looking for, and it's called **[Glympse](http://www.glympse.com/)**.

You can choose to share your location, set a timer on how long that location will be shared, and send the details (it's just a link) to any of your contacts via text message, Twitter, email, a bunch of other messaging apps etc.

What I like about this is that you can **limit how long your location is shared** and (if you specify a destination) **Glympse estimates your time of arrival based on current speed** and lets your friends know when to expect you.

Available on [iOS, Android, and Windows Phone](http://www.glympse.com/get-glympse).

[image: Glympse share screen]

***Set a timer on how long to share and whom to send to***

[image: Glympse app main screen]

***Main screen where details are shown***

Comment: I tested it today extensively. Was a bit disappointed that the app uses driving a car as the main mode of transportation. Actually, then waze is doing a far better job. However, the people behind Glympse are quite responsive on feature requests. I asked for the feature to use Glympse outside the car, ie. walking, public transport etc. So the app remains on my phone

Comment: came here to say Glympse. It's a great way to find someone in realtime.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, [Google Latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Latitude)!

Ok, last year they merged it with google+, so now it's just under locations in that app, but it allows you to share your GPS location with other contacts or friends, on a pinpoint or city-wide location.

It used to look like this:

[image]

[source](http://googlesystem.blogspot.co.nz/2011/02/google-latitude-check-ins.html)

But now, while still similar, is in Google+, and you can activate it [as per the following instructions on Android or iOS](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3302509?hl=en).

For example, today I was with friends travelling in four cars to Akaroa, New Zealand. Several of us use the app, and every so often we were stopping, and would immediately check to see how far along the other cars were, whether they were already there or lagging behind.  It updates every few minutes and works very well..

In London, several friends used to use it as well, and we'd see them all making a bee-line for a pub after work, for example, and could see when someone was running late.

Comment: seems to be in the right direction, but you can't selectively share your location with messaging, like you do with waze.

Answer (score 10):

If you and your follower both have iOS devices, [Find My Friends](https://www.apple.com/apps/find-my-friends/) can do what you are asking for.

Answer (score 4):

This is (finally!) possible [from within the Google Maps app](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3302509). Simply open the menu, tap "Location sharing" and send a link to any of your contacts or as a simple message. It can be be unlimited or restricted to a certain period of time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned "send a text message to have someone be able to follow me". Basic iPhone Message has a new feature to send your location, but not to set up a tracking relationship.

You might be interested in our app Group Tracker ⊚. Currently available on [iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/group-tracker-by-russell-harper/id858739714?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4), undergoing a *significant* revision for iOS 8, with version 1.3 to be released shortly.

It's intended uses are mostly ad-hoc groups based on physical proximity: tour groups, school & family outings, conferences & conventions, and assistance with mobility issues, translation, or taking pictures.

**Bonus offer**: if anyone loads it in the next week and sets his/her nickname as 'se-travel' we'll give them a free pro upgrade. I'll check once a day or so and indicate winners on Twitter @GTMobileApp.

BTW, great fan of Waze, too. I always check it before heading out!

Comment: Hi Buddy, great to see that you are participating. Please indicate clearly that the app you're recommending is one that you develop/work at following the [full disclosure principle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15787)

Comment: @BartArondson I think that fact is overwhelmingly clear based on the 'bonus offer' segment of the answer.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yes, it's clear, just as it is clear how every other brand is behind their own ads. It doesn't make it less of an ad. I think there's (subtle) a difference between: "Hey, I make this product and I think it could answer your question" (preferred) and "Hey, this product answers your questions, use it now and get the pro version free!" (the current answer). It's not a big deal and didn't downvote, but seeing as Buddy is new I thought I would point it out.

Comment: Made it clear it's our app. I don't normally promote in SE, usually using it for development questions, just happened to see the title in the side bar.

Answer (score 1):

Another app is called [GrouVigate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wavesoftware.social.grouvigate).

It allows you to start an activity and share it between your friends.
Then you will see each of your friends' position and route.

Very simple and intuitive to operate.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wavesoftware.social.grouvigate